# How to setup Umbraco 6.1.2 in Visual Studio 2012 with MVC enabled to use in TFS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, tfs, umbraco

What I want is a development environment in Visual Studio 2012 for Umbraco version 6.1.2  (latest stable version at the moment) with MVC as rendering engine so I can use Razor and integrate a MVC project in Umbraco.

I also want to be able to use a Team Foundation Sever to share and store the code.

The problem lies here: When I just download the Umbraco files from Umbraco or use WebMatrix to install an Umbraco site, I do not have access to the core files or a way to properly debug my install in Visual Studio.

So I need a way to build and debug/run Umbraco from Visual Studio.

I looked at a lot of posts, articles etc. (also on StackOverflow) but none seemed to address the latest Umbraco version (most about 4.5.x) and only a few about MVC. Old references, non existing project templates or templates to old versions of VS made me have to dig further. 
When I then found a solution, I thought about 2 things:
- 1 I need to check this solution
- 2 I should share this solution to a wider audience then it is getting now

Both two reasons are what made me post it here (clarification as asked)

Comment: I have edited my question, did I make myself clear enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, all you need to do is create an empty MVC4 project and add the Umbraco NuGet package, as this will also add the Core binaries package and set the dependencies for you.

Comment: I have a working development environment now, so I will not try this, but sounds like a better solution. any confirmation from others?

Comment: This is (almost) the best time to do it. Create a new project in your solution and add the Nuget package and point at the existing database and try it. You can then easily transfer your files and add any existing VS projects.

Comment: You are correct. I tried it and it works. That simple..., I do not see the umbraco folder etc included in the solution. Does this mean that I need to include those on deployment manually (or use your answer to @pomodororosso answer)

Comment: Personally, I always include everything that would potentially need to be available for a publish/deplyment, so yes I would use the technique in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524520/umbraco-tfs-including-hidden-files

Answer (score 3):

I found http://www.ben-morris.com/using-umbraco-6-to-create-an-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applicatio, which is the lastest article about the subject I could find (the download link in the article is to the old repository and not the current download page of Umbraco, though).

This setup worked really well for me  (Umbraco version 6.1.2)

1. Firstly, start an empty MVC 4 project in Visual Studio – make sure
   it is an empty project as you will not need any of the baggage that
   comes with other project templates.
2. Add the NuGet Umbraco Cms Core Binaries package which will manage the various dependencies and
   references that Umbraco 6 requires for you.
3. Copy all the files from
   the [Umbraco installation ZIP archive](http://our.umbraco.org/download) directly into your project in
   Visual Studio except the App_Code and Bin folders – you won’t need
   the binaries as they are managed by NuGet and the App_Code folder is not used in a web application project.

If you want Umbraco to play nice to MVC and be able to use Razor views, you should change the default rendering engine to MVC in Config\UmbracoSettings.config like so:

```
<templates>
  <useAspNetMasterPages>true</useAspNetMasterPages>
  <defaultRenderingEngine>Mvc</defaultRenderingEngine>
</templates>
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem you will have is ensuring all necessary files are checked in when modifying your umbraco site locally.

For example if you add a media image using the umbraco backend.  Visual studio won't automatically add it to the project and therefore source control for you so a check in will miss it.  You have to include the files in the project manually which can become tricky when big changes are made.

I'd like to know if anyone else has a better way of managing it.

Comment: I've asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524520/umbraco-tfs-including-hidden-files

Comment: good question and it looks like you received a good answer to it as well, will try and report back