# Umbraco & TFS - Including hidden files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, umbraco

I have an umbraco 6.* site set up in VS2012 and am using TFS for source control.

If I add templates, media items etc to the umbraco site through the umbraco backend the new files are not automatically included in the solution and I have to manually include the files so that they can be checked in to source control.

This can become quickly unmanageable when installing packages etc. or anything that creates a lot of files throughout different folder locations.

Does anyone have a solution to guarantee all files are checked into source control?

Changing source control is not an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I came across [this article](http://jamesrpatterson.com/blog/automatic-include-in-project-for-visual-studio) which explains how to 'blanket' include files or folders in a .csproj file. In a nutshell you can add the following references:

```
<Content Include="Path\To\Folder\**" />
<Content Include="Path\To\Folder\*.*" />
<Content Include="Path\To\Folder\*.jpg" >
```

So in the case of Umbraco you will first need to exclude the following folders from the project:

- /umbraco
- /umbraco_client
- /media
- /masterpages
- /views
- /macroscripts
- /xslt

then open up the .csproj file in a test editor and add:

```
<Content Include="umbraco\**" />
<Content Include="umbraco_client\**" />
<Content Include="media\**" />
<Content Include="masterpages\**" />
<Content Include="views\**" />
<Content Include="macroscripts\**" />
<Content Include="xslt\**" />
```

Save it, and then in VS reload your project.

Comment: What should be included and deployed from the App_Data directory?  I'm specifically wondering about packages/** preview/** and the guid-named package directories...

Comment: You can exclude app_data/preview but app_data/packages is needed.

Comment: Awesome post.  This just saved me a lot of time.  How is this information not in the Umbraco documentation?

Comment: Because it's fairly subjective and can be a little troublesome at times. I actually tend to exclude /media, /umbraco and /umbraco_client. Many developers won't use VS either and who really wants to get dirty in the csproj file?!

Comment: Well, no one likes mucking around in the project file.  However, my goal is to source control the solution in TFS, so the "blanket include" is exactly what I'm looking for (at least for certain directories).  Is there any harm in including the "umbraco" and "umbraco_client" directories?

Comment: None at all. I just find that unless I'm using CI, there is no point them being in the solution since they slow down a publish. For clarity, they are in source control though.